# Customize beamer slide numbering

Tags: beamer

I have around 250 slides which I am not able to compile as a single project (due to long compilation time). I have decided to keep them as separate projects. Is there a way to start the beamer slide numbering on a new project from the number 50? (So that I may merge these separate pdfs in the end)

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Please always include a short, but compilable test file in your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Manual:

You can manually increase the `framenumber` counter:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\addtocounter{framenumber}{49}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### Automatic

For an automatic solution, you could label the last frame in the previous document, let's call it `document2.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
  abc\pause fgdhj
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label=last]
  abc \ref{last}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

and then import the counter into your next document:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\usepackage{zref-xr}
\zxrsetup{toltxlabel}
\zexternaldocument*[foo-]{document2}
\setcounterref{framenumber}{foo-last}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

#### Split with lectures

Instead of using multiple files, you could also keep all your slides in one project and then use `\includeonlylecture{...}` to compile only parts of the presentation. This will automatically show the correct frame numbers:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]

\includeonlylecture{lec2}

\begin{document}

\lecture{lecture 1}{lec1}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\lecture{lecture 2}{lec2}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This made my presentation more organized. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Math_student You're welcome!

Comment: How can I apply the same concept to numbering the equations on beamer? ie., I'd like to start the equation numbering from Eq.(50) onwards in a new project.

Comment: @Math_student If you have a new question, ask a new question. And don't forget to include a MWE

Comment: Ok sure. What is MWE?

Comment: @Math_student A MWE is a short, but compilable test file. And when your at it, your question here is also still lacking one.